# Easy way to convert Java 8's LocalDateTime to Joda's LocalDateTime

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, java-time

Is there any easy way to convert Java 8's LocalDateTime to Joda's LocalDateTime?

One of the ways is to convert it to String and then create Joda's LocalDateTime from that String.

Comment: Convert it to a ISO formatted `String` and parse it back again.  Convert it to milliseconds since the epoch

Comment: Yes. I did the same way.

Comment: Why do you want to use Joda Time if you already use `java.time`?

Comment: I'm using java.time in my application. My applications depends on a library which is using Joda time. This is a special case where I need this conversion.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Convert through epoch millis (essentially a `java.util.Date()`):

```
java.time.LocalDateTime java8LocalDateTime = java.time.LocalDateTime.now();

// Separate steps, showing intermediate types
java.time.ZonedDateTime java8ZonedDateTime = java8LocalDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
java.time.Instant java8Instant = java8ZonedDateTime.toInstant();
long millis = java8Instant.toEpochMilli();
org.joda.time.LocalDateTime jodaLocalDateTime = new org.joda.time.LocalDateTime(millis);

// Chained
org.joda.time.LocalDateTime jodaLocalDateTime =
        new org.joda.time.LocalDateTime(
            java8LocalDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                              .toInstant()
                              .toEpochMilli()
        );

// One-liner
org.joda.time.LocalDateTime jodaLocalDateTime = new org.joda.time.LocalDateTime(java8LocalDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```

Single line, but long, so "easy"? It's all relative.

Answer (score 6):

Both localDate types consist of `(year, month, date)`, so just copy those values:

```
public static org.joda.time.LocalDate toJoda(java.time.LocalDate input) {
    return new org.joda.time.LocalDate(input.getYear(),
                                       input.getMonthValue(),
                                       input.getDayOfMonth());
}
```

Comment: The question is about LocalDateTime, not LocalDate.

Comment: This advice is applicable to `LocalDateTime` too, but you will need to add some additional code converting milliseconds to nanoseconds and vice versa, because Joda's `LocalDateTime` has precision to milliseconds and Java's `LocalDateTime` has precision to nanoseconds.

Comment: Saying "you will just need to add additional code" is not helpful and doesn't pertain to the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

**A slightly shorter method:**
If you can get away with using a `ZoneOffset` instead of a `ZoneId` then the code may be shortened slightly.

```
java.time.LocalDateTime java8LDT = java.time.LocalDateTime.now();
org.joda.time.LocalDateTime jodaLDT = new org.joda.time.LocalDateTime(
    java8LDT.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli()
);
```

The call to the `atZone()` method can be dropped by providing the timezone offset to the `toInstant()` method.

**More detailed explanation**
Just to clarify, the step I have removed is with creating the intermediate ZonedDateTime object. This part of the sequence is still with the Java 8 API before anything to do with Joda.

The process of conversion first involves converting the Java 8 LocalDateTime to the number of millis since the epoch. This can be achieved in a couple of different ways. For example in Andreas' answer:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
long millis = instant.toEpochMilli();
```

Or my alternative:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
Instant instant = ldt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
long millis = instant.toEpochMilli();
```

The difference is that I am skipping creating a Java 8 ZonedDateTime and instead passing the timezone offset to the `toInstant()` method.

From this point on the two answers are the same.

```
org.joda.time.LocalDateTime jodaLocalDateTime = new org.joda.time.LocalDateTime(millis);
```

**Caveats**
This works well when converting using a consistent offset where no daylight savings changes apply. For example UTC is always +0:00. If you need to convert to a local timezone where the offset can change then you'll need the slightly longer answer using `atZone()`

A LocalDateTime with both API's (Java 8 and Joda) is a DateTime without a timezone. However, if you have the number of millis since the epoch then you need an offset to derive a date and time. The Java 8 API requires either an offset or timezone to be explicitly passed in, whereas the Joda API will use the system default if none is passed.

A more precise way to construct the Joda LocalDateTime would be:

```
org.joda.time.LocalDateTime jodaLocalDateTime = new org.joda.time.LocalDateTime(millis, DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

This will only use the timezone during construction to get the correct date and time. Once the constructor has completed the timezone will not form part of the object since LocalDateTime has no timezone.

Comment: Be careful: `java8LDT.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli()`leads to a different result than `java8LDT.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli()` for system not running at systemDefault UTC!!

Comment: You can get the suitable offset by `ZoneId.systemDefault().getRules().getOffset(java8LDT)`, but I think `atZone(..).toInstant()...`is far more easy.

Comment: It was just an example! In practice you wouldn't call `.now()` in Java 8 and convert to Joda when you could just get the current time directly from Joda. You need to know the implicit timezone that applies to `java8LDT` and use the correct offset. I can see why the example may have misled though.

Comment: `.now()` was not the Point. The difference is using of `systemDefault` instead of `ZoneOffset.UTC`. So the code of the selected answer runs on every machine, no matter which timezone is systemDefault.

Comment: I disagree that you should always use `systemDefault()`. For example lets say you have a system that standardizes on storing all timestamps in UTC. Converting one of these would be much safer by explicitly specifying UTC. If you use `systemDefault()` then your conversion could work on one server but not another. The selected answer works because `now()` would be using the default timezone.

Comment: The chosen solution works independently of the preset time zone, because the constructor of joda LocalDateTime uses this default zone (see documentation). It has nothing to do with `.now ()`. Your solution works only with default zone equal to UTC and not independently. Your solution seems to be a simplification of the chosen solution, but it isn't. That's why I wrote my initial comment. There is no easy way to determine the offset to the default zone without `atZone ()`.

Comment: And of course you should not always use `systemDefault()` and I never said that.